How to force trigger a pre-flight request on a "simple request"?
I am dealing with a server I don't have access to, and I need to perform a cross-origin api call on it.
What is kind of weird about this server is that it "half-supports" CORS.
If the browser sends a preflight, it does answer with CORS headers, however, if sends a GET, there are no CORS headers.
My problem is that the ressource I'm trying to read fall into what is called a "simple request", that do not normally trigger a pre-flight request... And the browser rejects the response because the Acess-Controll-Allow-Origin header is missing in the response
I already tried to add a dummy header to force the preflight (and it does), however, the server omits to allow my dummy header... And then I am still blocked...
How can I force trigger the pre-flight without adding headers ? Is there a solution to still access the ressource ?

"I already tried to add a dummy header to force the preflight (and it does), however, the server omits to allow my dummy header..." - even if that wasn't the case, there is no guarantee it would answer a following GET request with an Acess-Controll-Allow-Origin header then. (You're dealing with a "black box" with a faulty CORS implementation to begin with, so who could possibly tell.) "Is there a solution to still access the ressource ?" - treat this "I mess up CORS"-server like a server that doesn't support it at all - and use the usual "workaround" of a CORS proxy then ...?

There are valid use cases for "half-supporting CORS", as you call it; see https://wicg.github.io/private-network-access/#shortlinks. That may be the case of the server in question.
